# Integration of apache common vfs and mercurial

Tags: java, mercurial, apache-commons-vfs

Can Apache common vfs api retrieve/update/add files from/to the Mercurial version control system? Common vfs does have an interface api for accessing vcs. Is there a provider for Mercurial?

hbagchi

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is one.  Mercurial is very much built with a "you should have the whole history local" mindset.  Any remote access short of synchronization or casual web browsing is generally considered unsupported.  Even accessing mercurial repos over nfs or other network file systems is advised against.

There are a few projects that use mercurial as their backends (things like ikiwiki), but remote access isn't generally a suggested config.